# Transform a k-CNF formulae to conjunctions of boolean literals

Tags: logic, computational-complexity, machine-learning

The question comes from Mehryar Mohri's *Foundations of Machine Learning*. In Example 2.5 the book transform a $k$-CNF formula to conjunctions of boolean literals, but I can't understand the trick in the book.

Here is the definition of $k$-CNF formula:

> A conjunctive normal form(CNF) formula is a conjunction of disjunctions. A $k$-CNF formula is an expression of the form $T_1\land \ldots \land T_j$ with arbitrary length $j\in\mathbb{N}$ and with each term $T_i$ being a disjunction of at most $k$ Boolean attributes

and here is the trick:

> To do so, it suffices to associate to each $T_i$ a new variable. Then this can be done with the following bijection:
>   $$
> a_i(x_1)\lor\ldots\lor a_i(x_n)\to Y_{a_i(x_1),\ldots,a_i(x_n)}
> $$
>   where $a_i(x_j)$ denotes the assignment to $x_j$ in term $T_i$.

But how could this mapping be a bijection when $Y_{a_i(x_1),\ldots,a_i(x_n)}$ only has value 0 or 1? It'll be great if someone could give a detailed example showing how these things work. thx.

Comment: I believe your question is going to be hard for anyone who doesn't know what PAC-learnable is (or goes to the trouble of learning it).  If a week or so passes and no one here can help you, since this seems to be about machine learning, then you might want to ask somewhere like the computer science stack exchange.

Comment: @DanielV I'm sorry, maybe the way I describe this question is not clear. I just want to know how to transform the CNF formula to conjunctions of boolean literal with the bijection the book shows. It really has no relation with the PAC-learnability. I will modify the question, thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simbology is not so clear to me, but I think that, basically, we have that the *conjunct* $T_i$ in the $k$-CNF is a *disjunction* of literals : i.e. boolean vars or negated boolean vars.

I assume that the variables $x_j$ are the boolena variables; if so, they occur into $T_i$ as is or negated.

We introduce an "auxiliary" function $a_i$ associated to $T_i$ such that :

> $a(x_j)$ has the value of $x_j$ or $\lnot x_j$, according to the way in which the variable occurs into $T_i$.

If so, the new boolean variable $Y_{a_i(x_1), \ldots, a_i(x_n)}$ will "works" exactly as the original disjunction.

Comment: Actually the whole story is about proving that the complexity of learning such a k-CNF formula can be polynomial. I think the bijection here works as you said, though it is still not clear how this helps reducing the complexity. Maybe I should post another question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I had a bit of trouble grasping the definition of "$k$-CNF formula", which threw me off: any conjunction of disjunctions is a $k$-CNF so long as each disjunctive clause has at most $k$ terms; nowhere in the definition do we limit the number of disjunctive clauses we can use. If our variables are $x$ and $y$ (so $n=2$) and $k=2$, then all of the following are $k$-CNF's, because each disjunctive clause in parentheses has at most $k=2$ terms:

$
(x \lor y) \\
(x) \\
(x \lor \bar{y} ) \land (\bar{x} \lor \bar{y}) \\
(x \lor y) \land (x \lor \bar{y}) \land (\bar{x} \lor y) \land (x) \land (y) \land (\bar{y})
$

It's useful to note that the "Conjunction of Boolean literals" problem is just the $k$-CNF problem in the case $k=1$.

We want to come up with a $k$-CNF that is consistent with some set of given samples. For each possible disjunctive clause (there are $O(n^k)$ of them) we associate a binary variable, where the variable is 1 if the clause is included in our consistent $k$-CNF and 0 if it is not. As in the "Conjunction of Boolean literals" case, we initialize each variable to $1$ so that in the $n=2, k=2$ case our initial consistent $k$-CNF is

$
(x \lor y) \land (x \lor \bar{y}) \land (\bar{x} \lor y) \land (\bar{x} \lor \bar{y}) \land (x) \land (\bar{x}) \land (y) \land (\bar{y})
$

This CNF evaluates to False, but it's still consistent if the sample set is empty. We use the same rule as in the "Conjunction of Boolean literals" case: we consider each positive sample in turn, and we rule out all clauses that evaluate to False when given that sample as input. For example, if we observe that the $k$-CNF we're learning evaluates to True for the input $x=1, y=0$, then we calculate

$
(x \lor y) \to (1 \lor 0) = 1\\
(x \lor \bar{y}) \to (1 \lor 1) = 1\\
(\bar{x} \lor y) \to (0 \lor 0) = 0\\
(\bar{x} \lor \bar{y}) \to (0 \lor 1) = 1\\
(x) \to (1) = 1\\
(\bar{x}) \to (0) = 0\\
(y) \to (0) = 0\\
(\bar{y}) \to (1) = 1
$

Since $(\bar{x} \lor y)$, $(\bar{x})$, and $(y)$ evaluate to False, we take them out of our old consistent $k$-CNF so that our new consistent $k$-CNF is

$
(x \lor y) \land (x \lor \bar{y}) \land (\bar{x} \lor\bar{y}) \land (x) \land (\bar{y})
$

Each possible disjunctive clause can be included or excluded (2 choices) and there's $O(n^k)$ disjunctive clauses, so the total number of $k$-CNF's is $2^{O(n^k)}$. Using the notation of the book, the number of possible concepts then is $|C| = 2^{O(n^k)}$. The number of possible hypotheses is at least that many: $|H| \geq |C|$. The book says our sample complexity $m$ grows like $\log |H| = O(n^k) \log 2$, which is polynomial in $n$ but exponential in $k$. When we convert a $k$-term DNF to a $k$-CNF, the $n$ and the $k$ switch, so that learning a $k$-term DNF by using this $k$-CNF learning algorithm and converting has a sample complexity that grows exponentially with $n$.

Comment: the example is clear, thx!